# База SQLite3 - преобразовать время INTEGER в TEXT

Tags: sqlite, ассемблер, fasm

Обрабатываю базу SQLite, используя функции библиотеки `sqlite3.dll` на ассемблере. В общем случае проблем нет, однако застрял на столбце с датой и временем. На запрос `sqlite3_column_type()` функция возвращает тип данных `INTEGER=1`. Вопрос, как теперь преобразовать это значение в привычный формат времени типа: 2021.04.30 для вывода его на консоль Windows? Если открыть базу в программе **"SQLite Expert Personal"**, то в столбце с датой лежит 17-значное число, и что дальше с ним делать - не могу сообразить. Заранее спасибо!

[image: Столбец с датой/временем]

Comment: Зависит от того, какое представление времени использует тот, кто туда это значение пишет. Распространённый способ хранения времени в виде целого числа это [unix timestamp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

Comment: [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT host_key, name, strftime('%Y.%m.%d', creation_utc / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') FROM cookies;
```

У вас время хранится в микросекундах с 1 января 1601 года.

Comment: А как это вызвать на более низком уровне? Функцию `datetime` нужно оформить в виде оператора `SELECT` что-ли? Если да, то `prepare_v2` в этом случае возвращает ОК, а следующий за ней `step = SQLITE_ROW` (по-сути тоже ОК). И где мне теперь найти результат `datetime`, чтобы передать его в `strftime()`?. Кстати последнюю я вызываю из msvcrt.dll.

Comment: Ну да в виде `SELECT`. Запрос будет что-то вроде `SELECT strftime('%Y.%m.%d', datetime(creation_utc / 10000000, 'unixepoch')) FROM table_name`. Или в ассемблере запросы как-то иначе делаются?

Comment: оформил запрос как Вы указали - результат такой-же ОК. То-есть в регистре `EAX` получаю `prepare=0` + `step=64h`. По всей вероятности, запрос исправно отрабатывает, только непонятно, куда помещается его результат? Поэтому я пытался вызвать функцию `strftime()` из либы msvcrt.dll - в первом аргументе она ожидает адрес приёмного буфера, а во-втором его размер. Здесь прототип: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=msvc-160

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вы спрашиваете не о том. Вы в принципе не понимаете, как сделать `SELECT`, и не можете получить никаких данных из базы? Тогда задайте соответствующий новый вопрос. Я не знаю, как в ассемблере это всё происходит.

Comment: Все столбцы кроме времени я вывожу нормально. Для них предусмотрен другой оператор: `SELECT host_key, name, creation_utc FROM cookies`. Теперь, после `step` зову функцию ***sqlite3_column_text()*** и в регистре EAX получаю указатель на текстовую строку в указанном столбце (в данном случае ".mail.ru"). Остаётся вывести её на консоль при помощи той-же `printf()`. В результате имею содержимое столбцов `host_key + name`, а вот как получить дружелюбное время из `creation_utc` - не знаю.

Comment: Ну так делайте всë то же самое, только преобразовывайте creation_utc: SELECT host_key, name,  strftime('%Y.%m.%d', datetime(creation_utc / 10000000, 'unixepoch')) FROM cookies

Comment: `>>> Ну так делайте всë то же самое` - вот оказывается как надо было! Это работает, только время для всех строк одинаковое возвращает `2012.01.12`. Пробовал изменить аргумент с выводом дата + время `'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'`, так и секунды даже совпадают. `16:11:23`. Год должен быть как-минимум нынешний, но почему-то всегда возвращает 2012, хотя значения в базе разные.

Comment: А зачем тут делитель `10000000`? Это какая-то константа? Если изменить его на `8200000`, то дата получается 2021.04.04 (что больше похоже на правду) и время вроде зашевелилось. Как вариант, попробую сравнить дату+время с выхлопом "Mimikatz" и экспериментально подобрать этот делитель.

Comment: @PRODIGY, Я не знаком с веб-разработкой, поэтому не понял, что за формат у вас там. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Да, именно такой должен быть формат запроса в операторе `SELECT`. Вопрос решён, большое спасибо Вам за помощь!!!